# angular2 ng2-nvd3: could not load the module

Tags: d3.js, angular, ng2-nvd3

I am trying to add the [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/T4i7Zh?p=preview) into angular2-quickstart project. In `systemjs.config.js` define a map `ng2-nvd3`

```
map: {
      // our app is within the app folder
      app: 'app',
     ...
      // other libraries
      'ng2-nvd3':                   'npm:ng2-nvd3/lib/ng2-nvd3'      
    },
```

`app.module.ts`:

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import {nvD3} from 'ng2-nvd3';

import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';
import { AppService }  from './app.service';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule 
  ],
  declarations: [ 
    nvD3,
    AppComponent 
  ],
  bootstrap: [
    AppComponent 
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

and `app.component.ts`:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
declare let d3: any;
import {nvD3} from 'ng2-nvd3';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: 'app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
...
}
```

Add 3 lines to `index.html`:

```
<script src="node_modules/d3/d3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/nvd3/build/nv.d3.min.css"/>
    <script src="node_modules/nvd3/build/nv.d3.min.js"></script>
```

The error from the browser:

[image]

Any idea pls?

Answer (score 0):

You are saying your System.js configuration that root script for NVD3 is hosted here :

`'ng2-nvd3': 'npm:ng2-nvd3/lib/ng2-nvd3'`

But as I see you are trying to get script from this path: `href="node_modules/nvd3/build/nv.d3.min.js"/>`

Try to change in system.config.js

This line : `'ng2-nvd3': 'npm:ng2-nvd3/lib/ng2-nvd3'`

To this: `'ng2-nvd3': 'npm:ng2-nvd3/build/ng2-nvd3'`

Answer (score 0):

The mapping in your systemjs.config.js is incorrect. You need to change it to the below:

```
'ng2-nvd3': 'npm:ng2-nvd3/build/lib/ng2-nvd3.js'
```